Can a JTable cell be focused but not selected?
Imagine a TableCellRenderer that renders booleans as check boxes (I know Swing has it OOB, but we need our own for a few reasons)
Would this check make sense?
if (isSelected || hasFocus) {
    checkbox.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
}

Can a JTable cell be focused but not selected (the opposite can indeed happen if multiple row selection is allowed)?
I used a keyboard to move focus, but each time a focused cell gets selected as well. In the demo below, no cell is ever painted yellow, even if I use a keyboard for navigation. It feels as if the focused is a subset of the selected
package demos.table;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableFocusDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Focus Demo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // Sample data and column names
            Object[][] data = {
                {"John", Boolean.TRUE},
                {"Alice", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Bob", Boolean.TRUE}
            };
            String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Active"};

            JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));

            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
                @Override
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
                    checkBox.setSelected((Boolean) value);
                    if (isSelected) {
                        checkBox.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
                    } else if (hasFocus) {
                        checkBox.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); // Different color for focus
                    } else {
                        checkBox.setBackground(table.getBackground());
                    }
                    return checkBox;
                }
            });

            table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

If it's not true and a focused cell doesn't have to be selected, please show a small demo

@user85421 because hasFocus is evaluated after isSelected. If it's selected, it doesn't matter whether it has focus (the color is the same). If it's not, then it can't be focused (I reckon). It would make sense if there could be unselected but focused cells

A table has cells, which can show some data (e.g., strings, boolean). The table cells have certain properties and behavior.  If you render a table cell as a check box, what happens to a table cell?

Try using the DefaultTableCellRenderer and also use the AbstractTableModel to render the boolean value as a checkbox. You will be able to try your code and render the cells in different colors and also a checkbox. Refer these Java Tutorials on JTable : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

In the code in your question, the JTable is configured such that only a single cell can be selected and in such a case, the default JTable behavior is to select the cell that has gained focus. If you hold Ctrl key and click the mouse on the selected cell, its background becomes yellow, which means that the cell has focus but is not selected. So it appears that you do not want the default behavior. Rather you want a cell to not be selected when it gains focus. Is that correct? If it is, then how does the user select a cell?
